# Getting aws data in terraform without creating resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Any ideas on how to get ALL of the data for a resources not created via terraform ?

This is assuming I do not have filters/ids.

I just want to view all of the instances of a resource (not created via terraform)

If that is not possible,
How do I view all the resources with the filter of **same tag**.

```
data "aws_eip" "by_tags" {
  tags = {
    Env = "DEV"
  }
}
```

Terraform errors with

```
Error: multiple Elastic IPs matched; use additional constraints to reduce matches to a single Elastic IP
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bulk import these existing resources into terraform format with a tool like [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you **can't do this**. You must know something about the EC2 Transit Gateway VPN which you want to find. If not `tags`, then maybe its `id`, or some values for `filter` option.

If you run the data source without any attributes you will get an error, which you are getting.

You can check [filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-transit-gateway-attachments.html) available for `transit-gateway-attachment` and see if you can use any of them, instead of name which you don't know.